# How in scout with Algolia make count methods?

Tags: laravel, algolia

Reading how works search method of scout with Algolia driver at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout#searching
I wonder can I to implement count and paginate methods

In code like :

```
if(empty($page)) {
    $returnedData = User::search($key)->get(); // get all data
} else {
    $returnedData = User::search($key)
        ->paginate($rowsPerPage, null, null, $page); // Get only data by $page
    $totalRowsCount = User::search($key) // Get total number of rows to create paginator
        ->getTotalCount(results: $returnedData);
}
```

I got error :

```
 Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::getTotalCount does not exist.
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:112
```

In which way can I do it ? I am not sure which value must be set into results patrameter...

In docs on prior version https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/scout I found  details of this method, but I do not
see can it be used under 10(it is not mentioned in 10 docs).

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
"algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^3.4",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use this method `getTotalCount`, instead `paginate` gives you a count of the total results.

read docs explanation: [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#pagination)

you can find `total` count at last in `meta (object)`:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Eladio Schroeder Sr.",
        "email": "therese28@example.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Liliana Mayert",
        "email": "evandervort@example.com"
    }
],
"links":{
    "first": "http://example.com/users?page=1",
    "last": "http://example.com/users?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},
"meta":{
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "path": "http://example.com/users",
    "per_page": 15,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 10
 }
}
```